# Angular2 Jasmine Test Image Source

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, gulp-karma

I have a component with an image in template

```
 <div class="logo"><img src="../images/logo.png"/></div>
```

When running karma task it throws such error

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "../images/logo.png"
```

To mention that app renders the image fine , only karma is complaining.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
it('should render the logo', async(() => {
  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
  expect(compiled.querySelector('div.logo>img').src).toContain('/images/logo.png');
}));
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Just tried it myself and it works.

Comment: This verifies that the image element exists and the source points to a specific URL string. But How to check that '/images/logo.png' actually exists?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you are using karma-jasmine to run the test. The files will be hosted on port 9876.

Let's say your img src is `./assets/images/logo.png`, then you should expect the src to be `http://localhost:9876/assets/images/logo.png` instead of just `./assets/images/logo.png`

Comment: Please provide a code example, I think that's what the asker was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use proxies and files property in karma.conf.js to serve files and proxy it.

Add files to be served in files property

```
{ pattern: './src/assets/**', watched: false, included:false, served:true, nocache:false }
```

Also to proxy these files with different url/ path, update proxies property

```
proxies: {
   '/assets/': '/base/src/assets/'
}
```

Now, when you try to access `http://localhost:9876/assets/logo.png` it will be a proxy call to `src/assets/logo.png` (all src assets are accessible like this as well `http://localhost:9876/base/src/assets/logo.png` )